# Why does my custom components with child.type.name returns a "t" for each one of them?

Tags: reactjs

I have a weird issue that only occurs when I build my React App and maybe someone can help me to explain what is happening?

I created a form with custom components like this:

```
<Form>
    <Input type="text" name="name" value="">Description</Input>
    <Textarea name="name" value="">Message</Textarea>
    <Submit>Send Request</Submit>
</Form>
```

When I run this setup on my localhost, each component have their real name returned when I call `child.type.name` (like Input, Textarea and Submit), but when I run the exact same structure on my build bundle it returns "t" for each one of them?

Comment: Isn't it simply the code minifier in action ?

Comment: Yes, it seems like you were correct and the class name get minified, so I can't use that as an identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UglifyJS via Webpack is taking care of this for you.

If you want to use `child.name` to identify components, it is better to define `displayName` and use `child.type.displayName`

Add this to any React Component via:

`static displayName = 'coolComponentName'`

Comment: Great, that definitely helped :)